# Handling listview’s IsRefreshing when concurrent tasks are executed

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a pull-to-refreshed-enabled listview where its IsRefreshing is binding to IsBusy property of the viewmodel. IsBusy is changed to true when the command is started and set to false when ended or fails. The problem is when user executes the command twice or more. When the first task is done, it sets the IsBusy to false making the listview’s activity indicator invisible. However, the second task is still running. I don’t want to set the IsBusy to false until all tasks are done. How can I achieve this?

EDIT:

[image]

The UI has segmented controls shown above and each control calls the command.

Comment: `if (IsBusy) return;` ?

Answer (score 0):

As @Gerald said, In your command inside the viewmodel, before setting `IsBusy` to true, check if it is not true first.  If not set it to true, otherwise return

```
private void DoCommand()
{
 If (IsBusy) return; 
 IsBusy = true; 
  // rest of you code here 
  // IsBusy = false; 
}
```

Comment: Problem is the UI, there are segmented controls and each calls the command. So if the user presses the control 2 and IsBusy is true, control 2 is selected but the listview shows different data.

Comment: added a screenshot of the UI

Comment: I thought the command is called when you pull to referesh . Can you explain according to your UI please ?

Comment: The command is called when any of the segmented control is tapped or the listview is pulled to refresh. Listview has IsRefreshing binded to IsBusy. So  when a the segmented control pressed, it also calls the command and IsBusy is set to true.

Comment: So you pull the list to refresh it , and when you tap the element you refresh the list also ?